# Question regarding webpart and reading/uploading images

Tags: spfx-webparts, modern-document-library

**Scenario:**

I have a Modern Webpart written in ReactJS, it allows user to filter images based on custom attributes that I have in a json file that is mapped to image file names. Currently the images live inside the webpart asset folder in src.

**Problem:**

I am hoping to add the function to allow user to upload images. Since webparts are client-side. I obviously can't save the uploaded images to the CDN hosting the webpart.

**My solution and thus this question:**

My planned solution is to have the webpart pull from a document library and store newly uploaded images there. But I am not sure if this is feasible - actually, I don't even know if this is the prefered solution.

If anyone can shed some light on this scenario, I will be forever grateful!